# Gradle Maven Plugin: compiling subprojects

Tags: java, maven, gradle, publishing

I have a project structure like this:

```
A
  src
    ...
  build.gradle
B
  src
    ...
  build.gradle
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

Module A `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
apply plugin: "java"

dependencies {
    compile project(':B')
}

// Maven configurations.
apply plugin: "maven-publish"

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives sourceJar
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://..." }
    }

    publications {
         mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
             groupId = "..."
             artifactId = "..."
             version = "..."

            from components.java
         }
    }
}
```

It compiles just fine but when it gets published, user gets an error that dependency `default:B:unspecified` cannot be resolved. How do I tell Gradle Maven plugin to statically compile module B into the artifact being published (rather than list it as a dependency)?

The whole project is a bit more complex and I do not want to either duplicate B source nor publish module B to Maven as a standalone library.